# Filling table from database thymeleaf

Tags: html, database, thymeleaf

I want to fill calendar which is formatted as a table - each column is a different day of week, each row is a different hour. I think i need to send two parameters to controller (i have day and hour as two different fields) and as a return get event name.

I know how to get data form database and show it in new rows (for example: [Springboot + thymeleaf displaying database contents in html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45855614/springboot-thymeleaf-displaying-database-contents-in-html-table))

I found how to pass the parameters to controller but only as a link/button to delete item from database. (for example: [Passing two values from HTML to Controller using Thymeleaf th:href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617512/passing-two-values-from-html-to-controller-using-thymeleaf-thhref))

Unfortunately i don't know how to connect that...

Here is my part of my controller

```
@GetMapping("/event/eventList/{dayOfWeek}/{time}")
public String getEvent(@PathVariable String dayOfWeek, @PathVariable String time) {
    Event byDayOfWeekAndTime = eventRepository.findByDayOfWeekAndTime(dayOfWeek, time);
    String eventName = byDayOfWeekAndTime.getEventName();
    return eventName;
}
```

And here is what i wrote in html:

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row">08:00</th>
    <td th:action="@{/event/eventList/{dayOfWeek}/{time} (dayOfWeek='monday', time='08:00')}"></td>
</tr>
```

And as i said i don't know how to do it or even if my thinking is correct.

Thanks!

Update:

After changing my controller like in the answer i still struggle with thymeleaf. I stil have to use th:action to get answer from controller?

Previously, when i just have get data from database i was doing this like that:

```
    <tr th:each="variableName : ${modelNameFromController}">
    <td th:text="${variableName.id}"></td>
    <td th:text="${variableName.email}"></td>
    <td th:text="${variableName.created}"></td>
</tr>
```

This time i need to send new parameters each time (or send it once to get one response to fill only one cell in a table) So I've tried something like this:

```
 <td th:action="@{/event/eventList/Monday/08:00}" th:text="${event.eventName}"></td>
```

But as you can imagine it didn't work :)

Help!

Answer (score 0):

It is pointless to add a th:action-attribute to a td-element. Try something like the following snippet (if you are hard-coding day and time, just write it directly to the link):

```
<tr>
    <th>08:00</th>
    <td>
        <a th:href="@{/event/eventList/monday/08:00}">
            Click me
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

If you like to use a form replace the a-element by:

```
<form th:action="@{/event/eventList/monday/08:00}">
   <button>Click me</button>
</form>
```

## Update

Your controller requires some adjustment:

```
@GetMapping("/event/eventList/{dayOfWeek}/{time}")
public String getEvent(
  @PathVariable("dayOfWeek") String dayOfWeek,
  @PathVariable("time") String time),
  Model model // That's one way to interact with the M in MVC
{
    // Log dayOfWeek and time
    Event byDayOfWeekAndTime = eventRepository.findByDayOfWeekAndTime(dayOfWeek, time);
    model.addAttribute("event", byDayOfWeekAndTime); // That's  what you are missing
    String eventName = byDayOfWeekAndTime.getEventName();
    return eventName;
}
```

You can access "event" in your template now, e.g.:

```
<p th:text="${event}"></p>
```

Comment: ok, this will give me a button/link. What I want is to pass to controller day and time and in return receive event name that will be displayed in a table.

Comment: ... and where is the problem? I wouldn't recomment path-variables but that's just a style issue. Have a look at my updated code. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Ok, I see it now. Your controller doesn't add anything to the model. Have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately I'm still struggling with code in template. I have updated my question to describe my problem.

Comment: So you are trying to update a single cell of the rendered view? Unfortunately you need more than thymleaf to achieve that. That's javascript-stuff. .... but you can add all required entities to the model and use them in the template. That requires a sufficient data-structure, e.g. a Map<Integer, Map<String, Event>> where the Integer-key is the day of week and the String-key the time ("08:00", ...).

Comment: Whit the data structure mentioned above you can iterate over the days of week in the template <tr th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence( 1, 7)}">, and then iterate over a defined set of times e.g. {"08:00", "09:00", ..} or another sequence 0 ... 23 and check if there is a coresponding entry in the mentioned map of maps.

Comment: Could you explain iterations in a template?